# Add a new item to the ItemsSource of a Datagrid without refering Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Suppose I have a Person Class as shown below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("People");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a datagrid in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid x:Key="maindg" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" KeyDown="maindg_KeyDown"/>
```

Now in MainWindow.xaml.cs I want to do something like below **without refering MainWindowViewModel**:

```
private void maindg_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

    MainWindowViewModel.People.Add(new Person());
}
```

**What I have tried:**

```
private void maindg_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

    maindg.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().Add(new Person());
}
```

But the above attempt failed. I mean I don't see a new row added to the DataGrid.

Comment: Why do you want to do this *without referring MainWindowViewModel*?

Comment: @Sheridan Because I am developing something like reusable control. In the question I did not mention that to keep the question simple.

Comment: *In the question I did not mention that to keep the question simple*... not so simple when someone has to ask though... always provide *all relevant information* in your question. I've seen people trying again and again to develop something generic that will save them time in WPF... *and fail*. Just write the code that you're supposed to write and it will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep it in mind the next time I ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use LINQ for this. `Cast<>()` is generating a new `IEumerable` of objects, and `ToList` creates a **copy** of the original list, which is why any changes to that list isn't making changes to the real list.

Just do a standard cast like this:

```
var list = (IList<Person>)maindg.ItemsSource;

list.Add(new Person());
```

Or to make it more generic:

```
var list = (IList)maindg.ItemsSource;

list.Add(new Person());
```

EDIT (Answer to second part of question):

Here is a generic way to create a new instance for the list without knowing the type.

It's assumed that the `ItemsSource` is a `generic` collection, and that the generic element has a public, parameterless constructor.

```
var list = (IList)maindg.ItemsSource;

var elementType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

var newElement = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);

list.Add(newElement);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan. Can you tell me if I was developing a reusable control, how can I make the above code more generic without using the name of the class Person. If you give me just the idea then it will be more than help. thanks again.

Comment: My second example should solve that.  It works because `ObservableCollection` implements both `IList<T>` and `IList`.  Just note that if you try to use `Add` with an object that the real generic collection doesn't support, you'll get an exception.

Comment: But in both the examples you use `list.Add(new Person());`

Comment: True, but the second example is of type `IList`, which defines Add as `Add(object value)`, which allows you to use any object type you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. But what I am trying to say is that : think DataGrid as a CustomContol that I am developing. So, I don't want to hardcode list.Add(new Person()); I want the developer who uses my CustomControl to specify what he wants to add to the list?

Comment: So, you want the code to automatically create a new instance of the type of the collection element when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for. You are really a genius.